Alternate form of solution of 2nd order ODE.
Using the annihilator method leads to a real solution of a non-homogeneous differential equation. But in this case I'm unable to get past the last step, which is complex.
This is the wikipedia article.
I tried solving this using sums of sines and cosines but that didn't work.
$$(c_1+c_2)e^{2x}\cos(x)+ie^{2x}(c_1-c_2)\sin(x)=y_c$$
But the solution is
$$y_c=e^{2x}(c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x))$$

@Moo But Isn't solution supposed to be Real. Or are you trying to imply that we can get rid of i by another constant?

If the solution was real from the start, then you have $c_2=\overline{c_1}$. Then the coefficient expressions reduce to $2Re(c_1)$ and $-2Im(c_1)$, so they are indeed real.

@LutzLehmann + That solves it :)
